Schwartz function dense in weighted Sobolev Space
Given a function $u$ on the Gevrey space with norm defined by
\begin{equation}
||u||_{G^{\sigma,s}}=||e^{\sigma|\xi|}(1+|\xi|)^s\hat{u}(\xi)||_{L^2}
\end{equation}
for $\sigma\geq 0$ and $s\in \mathbb{R}$. Does there exist a sequence of functions in the Schwartz space that converges to $u$ in the $G^{\sigma,s}$ norm?
I know this result is valid when $\sigma=0$. Does it remain valid for $\sigma>0$?
Any help or reference would be appreciated.

$\def\R{\mathbb R}$
Yes, it's true. The statement can be rewritten as: $\mathcal S(\R)\cap G^{\sigma,s}$ is dense in $G^{\sigma,s}$. (Note that the Schwartz space itself is not contained in $G^{\sigma,s}$; consider for instance the function $f$ with Fourier transform $\hat f(x)=e^{-(1+x^2)^{1/4}}$: $f\in \mathcal S(\R)$, but $f\not\in G^{\sigma,s}$).

First, you verify that the function $g:\xi\mapsto e^{\sigma|\xi|}(1+|\xi|)^s$ is equivalent to $h:\xi\mapsto e^{\sigma(1+|\xi|^2)^{1/2}}(1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}$, in the sense that their ratio is bounded from above and from below by positive constants.
With this, you can prove that the Banach space $G^{\sigma,s}$ is isomorphic (up to equivalent norms) to $L^2$ via the map
$$ T:G^{\sigma,s}\to L^2,\qquad Tu(\xi)=e^{\sigma(1+|\xi|^2)^{1/2}}(1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}(\hat u(\xi)). $$
You can write $T=M\circ\mathcal F$, where $\mathcal F$ is the Fourier transform, and $Mf(\xi):=h(\xi)f(\xi)$.
Now it is well-known that $C^\infty_c(\R)\subset L^2(\R)$ is dense, and it is straightforward that the image of $C^\infty_c(\R)$ through $M^{-1}$ coincides with $C^\infty_c(\R)$ itself, since $h$ and $1/h$ are smooth functions. Now, since $\mathcal F^{-1}$ maps $C^\infty_c(\R)$ into the Schwartz space, it follows that $T^{-1}(C^\infty_c(\R))\subset \mathcal S(\R)$. Since $T$ is bi-continuous, $T^{-1}(C^\infty_c(\R))$ is dense in $G^{\sigma,s}$, so $\mathcal S(\R)\cap G^{\sigma,s}$ is also dense in $G^{\sigma,s}$.

Thank you very much!
